# (Speed Challenge) Any faster method to calculate distance matrix between rows of two matrices, in terms of Euclidean distance?

Tags: r, performance, matrix, euclidean-distance

First of all, this is **NOT** the problem of [calculating Euclidean distance between two matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35106567/12158757).

Assuming I have two matrices `x` and `y`, e.g.,

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(15), ncol=5)
y <- matrix(rnorm(20), ncol=5)
```

where

```
> x
           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.6264538  1.5952808 0.4874291 -0.3053884 -0.6212406
[2,]  0.1836433  0.3295078 0.7383247  1.5117812 -2.2146999
[3,] -0.8356286 -0.8204684 0.5757814  0.3898432  1.1249309

> y
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -0.04493361 0.59390132 -1.98935170 -1.4707524 -0.10278773
[2,] -0.01619026 0.91897737  0.61982575 -0.4781501  0.38767161
[3,]  0.94383621 0.78213630 -0.05612874  0.4179416 -0.05380504
[4,]  0.82122120 0.07456498 -0.15579551  1.3586796 -1.37705956
```

Then I want to get distance matrix `distmat` of dimension 3-by-4, where the element `distmat[i,j]` is the value from `norm(x[1,]-y[2,],"2")` or `dist(rbind(x[1,],y[2,]))`.

- **My code**

```
distmat <- as.matrix(unname(unstack(within(idx<-expand.grid(seq(nrow(x)),seq(nrow(y))), d <-sqrt(rowSums((x[Var1,]-y[Var2,])**2))), d~Var2)))
```

which gives

```
> distmat
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
[1,] 3.016991 1.376622 2.065831 2.857002
[2,] 4.573625 3.336707 2.698124 1.412811
[3,] 3.764925 2.235186 2.743056 3.358577
```

but I don't think my code is elegant or efficient enough when with `x` and `y` of large number of rows.

- **Objective**

I am looking forward to a ***much faster*** and ***more elegant*** code with ***base R*** for this goal. Appreciated in advance!

- **Benchmark Template** (in updating)

For your convenience, you can use the following for benchmark to see if your code is faster:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(15000), ncol=5)
y <- matrix(rnorm(20000), ncol=5)
# my customized approach
method_ThomasIsCoding_v1 <- function() {
  as.matrix(unname(unstack(within(idx<-expand.grid(seq(nrow(x)),seq(nrow(y))), d <-sqrt(rowSums((x[Var1,]-y[Var2,])**2))), d~Var2)))
}
method_ThomasIsCoding_v2 <- function() {
  `dim<-`(with(idx<-expand.grid(seq(nrow(x)),seq(nrow(y))), sqrt(rowSums((x[Var1,]-y[Var2,])**2))),c(nrow(x),nrow(y)))
}
method_ThomasIsCoding_v3 <- function() {
  `dim<-`(with(idx1<-list(Var1 = rep(1:nrow(x), nrow(y)), Var2 = rep(1:nrow(y), each = nrow(x))), sqrt(rowSums((x[Var1,]-y[Var2,])**2))),c(nrow(x),nrow(y)))
}
# approach by AllanCameron
method_AllanCameron <- function()
{
  `dim<-`(sqrt(rowSums((x[rep(1:nrow(x), nrow(y)),] - y[rep(1:nrow(y), each = nrow(x)),])^2)), c(nrow(x), nrow(y)))
}
# approach by F.Prive
method_F.Prive <- function() {
  sqrt(outer(rowSums(x^2), rowSums(y^2), '+') - tcrossprod(x, 2 * y))
}
# an existing approach by A. Webb from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35107198/12158757
method_A.Webb <- function() {
  euclidean_distance <- function(p,q) sqrt(sum((p - q)**2))
  outer(
    data.frame(t(x)),
    data.frame(t(y)),
    Vectorize(euclidean_distance)
  )
}



bm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  method_ThomasIsCoding_v1(),
  method_ThomasIsCoding_v2(),
  method_ThomasIsCoding_v3(),
  method_AllanCameron(),
  method_F.Prive(),
  # method_A.Webb(),
  unit = "relative",
  check = "equivalent",
  times = 10
)
bm
```

such that

```
Unit: relative
                       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 method_ThomasIsCoding_v1() 9.471806 8.838704 7.308433 7.567879 6.989114 5.429136    10
 method_ThomasIsCoding_v2() 4.623405 4.469646 3.817199 4.024436 3.703473 2.854471    10
 method_ThomasIsCoding_v3() 4.881620 4.832024 4.070866 4.134011 3.924366 3.367746    10
      method_AllanCameron() 5.654533 5.279920 4.436071 4.772527 4.184927 3.157814    10
           method_F.Prive() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10
```

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35106567/how-to-calculate-euclidean-distance-between-two-matrices-in-r)? The `outer` method looks promising

Comment: @Sotos I saw it, but not the same thing I am after

Comment: This has been already asked a lot of times here.

Comment: @F.Privé are you sure? it is not the trivial one, the rows in a matrix is taken as a "elements" for calculating the distance...

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding I find you get an extra ~10% speedup on your v2 function by changing `idx<-expand.grid(seq(nrow(x)),seq(nrow(y)))` to `idx1<-list(Var1 = rep(1:nrow(x), nrow(y)), Var2 = rep(1:nrow(y), each = nrow(x)))`

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks for digging into it. I checked your finding, but it seems no improvement... see my updates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
method_XXX <- function() {
  sqrt(outer(rowSums(x^2), rowSums(y^2), '+') - tcrossprod(x, 2 * y))
}

Unit: relative
                       expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max
 method_ThomasIsCoding_v1() 12.151624 10.486417 9.213107 10.162740 10.235274 5.278517
 method_ThomasIsCoding_v2()  6.923647  6.055417 5.549395  6.161603  6.140484 3.438976
 method_ThomasIsCoding_v3()  7.133525  6.218283 5.709549  6.438797  6.382204 3.383227
      method_AllanCameron()  7.093680  6.071482 5.776172  6.447973  6.497385 3.608604
               method_XXX()  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000
```

Comment: Brilliant work! You reformulate the problem and simplify it from a math perspective. Like your solution!

Answer (score 2):

Here's two Rcpp functions and a few other new solutions:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(microbenchmark)

cppFunction('NumericMatrix crossdist(NumericMatrix x,NumericMatrix y){
  int n1=x.nrow(),n2=y.nrow(),ncol=x.ncol(),i,j,k;
  if(ncol!=y.ncol())throw std::runtime_error("Different column number");
  NumericMatrix out(n1,n2);
  for(i=0;i<n1;i++)for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
    double sum=0;
    for(k=0;k<ncol;k++)sum+=pow(x(i,k)-y(j,k),2);
    out(i,j)=sqrt(sum);
  }
  return out;
}')

cppFunction('NumericMatrix crossdist2(NumericMatrix x,NumericMatrix y){
  int n1=x.nrow(),n2=y.nrow(),ncol=x.ncol(),i,j,k;
  if(ncol!=y.ncol())throw std::runtime_error("Different column number");
  NumericMatrix out(n1,n2);
  double rs1[n1],rs2[n2],sum;
  for(i=0;i<n1;i++){sum=0;for(j=0;j<ncol;j++)sum+=pow(x(i,j),2);rs1[i]=sum;}
  for(i=0;i<n2;i++){sum=0;for(j=0;j<ncol;j++)sum+=pow(y(i,j),2);rs2[i]=sum;}
  for(i=0;i<n1;i++)for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
    sum=0;
    for(k=0;k<ncol;k++)sum+=x(i,k)*y(j,k);
    out(i,j)=sqrt(rs1[i]+rs2[j]-2*sum);
  }
  return out;
}')

x=matrix(rnorm(15000),,5)
y=matrix(rnorm(20000),,5)

b=microbenchmark(times=1000,
  crossdist(x,y),
  crossdist2(x,y),
  Rfast::dista(x,y),
  proxy::dist(x,y),
  pracma::distmat(x,y),
  as.matrix(pdist::pdist(x,y)),
  sqrt(outer(rowSums(x^2),rowSums(y^2),"+")-2*tcrossprod(x,y)),
  sqrt(outer(rowSums(x^2),rowSums(y^2),"+")-2*x%*%t(y)),
  sqrt(Rfast::Outer(Rfast::rowsums(y^2),Rfast::rowsums(x^2),"+")-2*Rfast::Tcrossprod(x,y)),
  sqrt(Rfast::Outer(Rfast::rowsums(y^2),Rfast::rowsums(x^2),"+")-2*x%*%t(y))
)

a=aggregate(b$time,list(b$expr),median)
a=a[order(a[,2]),]
writeLines(paste(sprintf("%.3f",a[,2]/min(a[,2])),gsub(" ","",a[,1])))
```

This shows the median time of a thousand runs relative to the fastest solution:

```
1.000 crossdist(x,y)
1.013 sqrt(Rfast::Outer(Rfast::rowsums(y^2),Rfast::rowsums(x^2),"+")-2*x%*%t(y))
1.053 crossdist2(x,y)
1.137 sqrt(Rfast::Outer(Rfast::rowsums(y^2),Rfast::rowsums(x^2),"+")-2*Rfast::Tcrossprod(x,y))
1.745 proxy::dist(x,y)
1.789 sqrt(outer(rowSums(x^2),rowSums(y^2),"+")-2*tcrossprod(x,y))
1.800 sqrt(outer(rowSums(x^2),rowSums(y^2),"+")-2*x%*%t(y))
2.257 Rfast::dista(x,y)
2.995 as.matrix(pdist::pdist(x,y))
3.662 pracma::distmat(x,y)
```

I don't know if it's a bug, but the matrix produced by `Rfast::outer` is a transposed version of the matrix produced by the regular `outer` function.

`tcrossprod(m1,m2)` is supposed to be slightly faster than `m1%*%t(m2)`, but there wasn't much difference in this benchmark:

```
> m1=matrix(rnorm(15e3),,5);m2=matrix(rnorm(2e4),,5)
> microbenchmark(times=1000,tcrossprod(m1,m2),m1%*%t(m2),Rfast::Tcrossprod(m1,m2))
Unit: milliseconds
                      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
        tcrossprod(m1, m2) 43.84316 44.06985 61.13149 44.21542 77.65599 338.6649  1000
              m1 %*% t(m2) 43.88956 44.11695 60.80872 44.29451 77.71928 186.3051  1000
 Rfast::Tcrossprod(m1, m2) 50.69726 52.52188 68.89744 55.57927 85.91948 194.9279  1000
```

This is a fast way to calculate the distance of row 1 in `m1` to row 1 in `m2`, row 2 in `m1` to row 2 in `m2`, and so on:

```
sqrt(rowSums((m1-m2)^2))
```

This is a fast way to calculate the distance of a vector `v` to each row of matrix `m`:

```
sqrt(rowSums(m^2)+sum(v^2)-2*m%*%as.matrix(v))[,1]
```

Comment: If you change the  ```Rfast::Outer(a,b)``` to ```Rfast::Outer(b,a)``` it will give the same as R's.

Answer (score 1):

The `proxy` package has a function for this.

```
library(proxy)
dist(x, y)

     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]    
[1,] 3.016991 1.376622 2.065831 2.857002
[2,] 4.573625 3.336707 2.698124 1.412811
[3,] 3.764925 2.235186 2.743056 3.358577
```

Comment: your `dist` from any package other than base R?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that its not the stats::dist function. Seems to be from the `proxy` package.

Comment: Just ran the benchmark and it outperforms your method by a factor of ~15, so may be still helpful.

Comment: Great that your approach is so excellent in terms of speed....I upvoted your answer, but I will wait if there is any solution written in base R only :)

Answer (score 1):

I've kept it simple and base R whilst managing a one-liner that gives a 3* speedup.

```r
`dim<-`(sqrt(rowSums((x[rep(1:nrow(x), nrow(y)),] - y[rep(1:nrow(y), each = nrow(x)),])^2)), c(nrow(x), nrow(y)))
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
# [1,] 3.016991 1.376622 2.065831 2.857002
# [2,] 4.573625 3.336707 2.698124 1.412811
# [3,] 3.764925 2.235186 2.743056 3.358577
```

Unfortunately my PC's memory choked on the tests with big matrices, so I had to reduce the dimensions by an order of magnitude to run the tests.

Full code shown:

```r
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(1500), ncol=5)
y <- matrix(rnorm(2000), ncol=5)
# my customized approach
method_ThomasIsCoding <- function() {
  as.matrix(unname(unstack(within(idx<-expand.grid(seq(nrow(x)),seq(nrow(y))), d <-sqrt(rowSums((x[Var1,]-y[Var2,])**2))), d~Var2)))
}
# an existing approach by A. Webb from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35107198/12158757
method_A.Webb <- function() {
  euclidean_distance <- function(p,q) sqrt(sum((p - q)**2))
  outer(
    data.frame(t(x)),
    data.frame(t(y)),
    Vectorize(euclidean_distance)
  )
}
# your approach
method_AllanCameron <- function()
{
  `dim<-`(sqrt(rowSums((x[rep(1:nrow(x), nrow(y)),] - y[rep(1:nrow(y), each = nrow(x)),])^2)), c(nrow(x), nrow(y)))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  method_ThomasIsCoding(),
  method_A.Webb(),
  method_AllanCameron(),
  times = 10
)
```

Result

```r
# Unit: milliseconds
#                     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  method_ThomasIsCoding()  63.08587  64.70988  69.59648  67.73379  75.90281  76.92903    10
#          method_A.Webb() 330.44824 349.90977 376.36962 368.52164 392.11780 446.57269    10
#    method_AllanCameron()  16.29938  18.20057  21.02634  20.45267  22.41767  31.28646    10
```

Comment: Good work! It seems you sacrificed space (i.e., memory resources) to gain the speed, since you are expanding the origin matrix to a larger one, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure. The RStudio profiler suggests this method uses less memory than either of the other methods. It seems to have a much smaller call stack, which I think is where it gets the speed boost.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, so you I ran your approach with large matrices in my benchmark, and you can see it in my updated post